# How to update post with Ajax (no plugin)

Tags: ajax

There was a tutorial a while back that was published to show how to ajax-ify publish/update posts, here's the code from it:

```
function my_post_type_xhr(){
    global $post;
    if('my_post_type' === $post->post_type){
        $post_url = admin_url('post.php'); #In case we're on post-new.php
        echo "
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                //Click handler - you might have to bind this click event another way
                $('input#publish, input#save-post').click(function(){
                    //Post to post.php
                    var postURL = '$post_url';

                    //Collate all post form data
                    var data = $('form#post').serializeArray();

                    //Set a trigger for our save_post action
                    data.push({foo_doing_ajax: true});

                    //The XHR Goodness
                    $.post(postURL, data, function(response){
                        var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
                        if(obj.success)
                            alert('Successfully saved post!');
                        else
                            alert('Something went wrong. ' + response);
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>";
    }
}
add_action('admin_head-post.php', 'my_post_type_xhr');
add_action('admin_head-post-new.php', 'my_post_type_xhr');
```

It also had a second part:

```
 add_action('save_post', 'save_my_post_type');
function save_my_post_type($post_id){
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;

    #If this is your post type
    if('my_post_type' === $_POST['post_type']){
        //Save any post meta here

        #We conditionally exit so we don't return the full wp-admin load if foo_doing_ajax is true
        if(isset($_POST['foo_doing_ajax']) && $_POST['foo_doing_ajax'] === true){
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            #Send a response
            echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
            exit;
            #You should keep this conditional to degrade gracefully for no JS
        }
    }
}
```

While this solution works, it has a couple flaws:

- In this code snippet, no message pop-ups saying the post type was saved
- In the code snippet, you can leave the post type with an alert asking you if you want to leave, even though the post is updated.

I really don't have an idea where to start with fixing these two problems. Like I said, the original tutorial works, but it has some flaws. I would just like the more improved version of the 2 code snippets from the original question/answer, but updated to fix the two problems. Not even sure if it's written all that well.

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't make your question rely on content outside. If the link is gone (and it will be), your question won't make any sense anymore. Also you might want to read [WPTRW and the AJAX chapter](http://www.wptherightway.org/en/javascript/README.html).

Comment: Fair enough, should I just post the entire code snippet then? From the old tutorial?

Comment: Add whatever you think the question needs (as an [edit] to the question). At least as long as the license under which the content was published allows to.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but for future reference, check out the answer I gave on the original question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60776/is-there-an-easy-way-to-ajax-ify-saving-of-post). The gist is:

**Confirmation Dialog**

The alert is generated in *wp-admin/js/post.js* and *wp-includes/js/autosave.js*. Theoretically, you should be able to use the following line of code in your $.post success function:

```
wp.autosave.initialCompareString = wp.autosave.getCompareString();
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Instead, you can supercede the beforeunload function as so:

```
// Replaces wp.autosave.initialCompareString
var ajax_updated = false;

// Supercede the WP beforeunload function                  
$(window).unbind('beforeunload.edit-post');
$(window).on( 'beforeunload.edit-post', function() {
        var editor = typeof tinymce !== 'undefined' && tinymce.get('content');

        // Use our "ajax_updated" var instead of wp.autosave.initialCompareString
        if ( ( editor && !editor.isHidden() && editor.isDirty() ) ||
                ( wp.autosave && wp.autosave.getCompareString() != ajax_updated) ) {
                return postL10n.saveAlert; 
        }
});
```

And then change ajax_updated to the right content in your $.post success function, as so:

```
// Mark TinyMCE as saved
if (typeof tinyMCE !== 'undefined') {
        for (id in tinyMCE.editors) {
                var editor = tinyMCE.get(id);
                editor.isNotDirty = true;
        }
}   
// Update the saved content for the beforeunload check
ajax_updated = wp.autosave.getCompareString();
```

**Adding an alert message**

You also asked about adding an alert message. You could do that a lot of different ways. The simplest and ugliest would be to use the javascript alert() function, like this:

```
alert("Post saved");
```

Personally, I prefer the [jquery notify library](https://notifyjs.com/). After including the library, you would place this in your success and failure functions, respectively:

```
$.notify('Post saved','success');
$.notify('Something went wrong','error');
```

Comment: Thanks for this: you put me on the right path on a completely different project. (I ended up needing to add `$( window ).unbind( 'beforeunload.edit-post' );` and `$( window ).unbind( 'beforeunload.post-new' );`.